# How to use the vscode's debug mode to the Vision Transformer model implemented in timm?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch

I'm looking at the implementation of the ViT model in `timm`, hoping to understand the transfer process of the internal module parameters of this model. But I encountered difficulties when using vscode's debugging mode (I have set `"justMyCode": false`, so I can jump to other packages).

First of all, let me show you the timm code structure mainly used in this question.
I observed that the way that `timm` generates models is similar to `torchvision`, except that `timm` first uses `Python Decorators` to store the model generation function in a `dict`, and then calls the function in the `dict` to generate the model:

```
@register_model   # Decorates
def vit_base_patch16_224(pretrained=False, **kwargs):
    model_kwargs = dict(patch_size=16, embed_dim=768, depth=12, num_heads=12, **kwargs)
    model = _create_vision_transformer('vit_base_patch16_224', pretrained=pretrained, **model_kwargs)
    return model    # generate ViT
```

You can see that only the `dict` assignment operation is done in the decorator, which corresponds to a string name for each model generation function, and saves it in the dictionary `_model_entrypoints`:

```
_model_entrypoints = {}  # mapping of model names to entrypoint fns

def register_model(fn):
    ......
    model_name = fn.__name__
    _model_entrypoints[model_name] = fn
    ......
    return fn
```

Next are the specific problems I encountered.
First: Why does `print()` in the source code of the ViT model not take effect (I added `print()` to both `__init__` and `forward` respectively)? And why the debug mode cannot enter the `class VisionTransformer(nn.Module):` that has a breakpoint?

```
class VisionTransformer(nn.Module):   # original code in timm/models/vision_transformer.py
    def __init__(self,......)
        super().__init__()
        print("vit: __init__")  # I added
        ...
        ...
    def forward(self, x):
        print("vit: forward")  # I added
        ...
```

Second: As shown in the following code, I tried to change the statement that calls the dictionary to the statement that calls the function directly in the `create_model()` of `factory.py`. There should be no difference in principle, but an error of `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument` will be reported:

```
def create_model(  # original code in timm/models/factory.py
        model_name,
        pretrained=False,
        checkpoint_path='',
        scriptable=None,
        exportable=None,
        no_jit=None,
        **kwargs):
    ...
    create_fn = model_entrypoint(model_name)   # Call the function in the dict in the previously mentioned decorator
    ...
    with set_layer_config(scriptable=scriptable, exportable=exportable, no_jit=no_jit):
        model = create_fn(pretrained=pretrained, **kwargs)    
        # ↑↑↑ original model generation sentence: The sentence will not report an error.
        # ↓↓↓ I added: The sentence will report got an [unexpected keyword argument 'use_mean_pooling'] error
        model = timm.models.vision_transformer.vit_base_patch16_224(pretrained=pretrained, **kwargs)    
    ...
    return model
```

The following is my test code, calling `create_model()` in `factory.py`:

```
...
model = create_model(
        'vit_base_patch16_224',
        pretrained=False,
        num_classes=1,
        drop_rate=0.0,
        drop_path_rate=0.1,
        attn_drop_rate=0.0,
        drop_block_rate=None,
        use_mean_pooling=True,
        init_scale=0.001,
)
...
...
```

I am so confused about the source code of `timm`. I would be very grateful if any of the above two questions is answered.